# Circular Dependency bidirectional @OneToMany JPA relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Given the following two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Goal {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String description;

private BigDecimal amount;

@Email
private String email;

@Email
private String supervisorEmail;

private LocalDateTime deadline;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(nullable = false)
private PaymentPurpose purpose;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private GoalStatus status;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;



//getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Goal> goals;

    //getters and setters

}
```

When I call `goalRepository.findAll()` after inserting a Dummy `Goal` with a Dummy `Person`, I get a never ending recursive loop.
Adding `@JsonIgnore` to the `goal` list in `Person` didn't help. I also tried `@JsonIgnoreProperties`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the exception is raised by *jackson*, try to use these two annotations:

- @JsonManagedReference
- @JsonBackReference

see http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion